# Core Data and Semi-Permanent Data

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data

I'm curious how, at a high level, people go about using Core Data to cache particular information on a semi-permanent basis.  For example, there is some information that I'd like to pull off a remote server and then persist for say no more than 24 hours, other data that I would want to persist for, say, no more than 10 minutes.

I don't want to have to reload it (since it's coming off the web) every time a view is loaded.  But, at the same time, I don't want it being reused if the data has expired. Instead, I want to clear the store and reload.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems pretty straightforward to me. Assuming everything is timestamped, it would be pretty easy to periodically delete expired items from the Core Data store.

You could approach it two ways:

For something like a Twitter client, you would probably have the views just show whatever is in the store. At the time you download new data, you would also purge expired old data. So it's just a part of your update process.

If you wanted to be sure you *never* showed expired data, you would include the expiration time when you query the store. In other words, you filter at the time you view the data. You could also use a timer to periodically update the view if you felt it was necessary. In this case you might have expired data in the store that you're just hiding; I'd probably wait until download to actually purge it, though.

Comment: Thanks.  My only issue is that I want to flush all of an entity if it looks expired, but, perhaps I can deal with this by just having a separate entity that tracks when particular entities were last updated.